# Can I bundle two MPI messages?

Tags: c++, c, cluster-computing, mpi, openmpi

I am trying to do an all-to-one communication out-of-order.  Basically I have multiple floating point arrays of the same size, identified by an integer id.

Each message should look like:

```
<int id><float array data>
```

On the receiver side, it knows exactly how many arrays are there, and thus sets up exact number of recvs.  Upon receiving a message, it parses the id and put data into the right place.  The problem is that a message could be sent from any other processes to the receiving process.  (e.g. the producers have a work queue structure, and process whichever id is available on the queue.)

Since MPI only guarantees P2P in order delivery, I can't trivially put integer id and FP data in two messages, otherwise receiver might not be able to match id with data.  MPI doesn't allow two types of data in one send as well.

I can only think of two approaches.

1) Receiver has an array of size m (source[m]), m being number of sending nodes.  Sender sends id first, then the data.  Receiver saves id to source[i] after receiving an integer message from sender i.  Upon receiving a FP array from sender i, it checks source[i], get the id, and moves data to the right place.  It works because MPI guarantees in-order P2P communication.  It requires receiver to keep state information for each sender.  To make matter worse, if a single sending process can have two ids sent before data (e.g. multi-threaded), this mechanism won't work.

2) Treat id and FP as bytes, and copy them into a send buffer.  Send them as MPI_CHAR, and receiver casts them back to an integer and a FP array.  Then I need to pay the addition cost of copying things into a byte buffer on sender side.  The total temporary buffer also grows as I grow number of threads within an MPI process.

Neither of them are perfect solutions.  I don't want to lock anything inside a process.  I wonder if any of you have better suggestions.

Edit: The code will be run on a shared cluster with infiniband.  The machines will be randomly assigned.  So I don't think TCP sockets will be able to help me here.  In addition, IPoIB looks expensive.  I do need the full 40Gbps speed for communication, and keep CPU doing the computation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As somebody already wrote, you can use `MPI_ANY_SOURCE` to receive from any source. To send two different kind of data in a single send you can use a [derived datatype](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-11-html/node54.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"

#define asize 10

typedef struct data_ {
  int   id;
  float array[asize];
} data;

int main() {

  MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);

  int rank = -1;
  int size = -1;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);

  data buffer;    
 // Define and commit a new datatype
  int          blocklength [2];
  MPI_Aint     displacement[2];
  MPI_Datatype datatypes   [2];
  MPI_Datatype mpi_tdata;

  MPI_Aint     startid,startarray;
  MPI_Get_address(&(buffer.id),&startid);
  MPI_Get_address(&(buffer.array[0]),&startarray);

  blocklength [0] = 1;
  blocklength [1] = asize;
  displacement[0] = 0;
  displacement[1] = startarray - startid;
  datatypes   [0] = MPI_INT;
  datatypes   [1] = MPI_FLOAT;

  MPI_Type_create_struct(2,blocklength,displacement,datatypes,&mpi_tdata);
  MPI_Type_commit(&mpi_tdata);

  if (rank == 0) {
    int        count = 0;
    MPI_Status status;

    while (count < size-1 ) {
      // Non-blocking receive
      printf("Receiving message %d\n",count);
      MPI_Recv(&buffer,1,mpi_tdata,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
      printf("Message tag %d, first entry %g\n",buffer.id,buffer.array[0]);
      // Counting the received messages 
      count++;
    }

  } else {
    // Initialize buffer to be sent
    buffer.id = rank;
    for (int ii = 0; ii < size; ii++) {
      buffer.array[ii] = 10*rank + ii;
    }
    // Send buffer
    MPI_Send(&buffer,1,mpi_tdata,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }

  MPI_Type_free(&mpi_tdata);

  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I agree that using MPI_ANY_SOURCE and tag "should" work, but it's not behaving as specified in my code.  I will try my own datatype this time.  Thanks!

Comment: What you propose is highly unportable and would not work in heterogeneous environments. A portable solution would be to register an MPI structure type with two fields, one of type `MPI_INT` and block length of `1` and one of type `MPI_FLOAT` and block length of `asize`.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify `MPI_ANY_SOURCE` as the source rank in the receive function, then sort the messages using their tags, which is easier than creating custom messages. Here's a simplified example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main() {
    MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);
    int rank=0;
    int size=1;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);

    // Receiver is the last node for simplicity in the arrays
    if (rank == size-1) {
        // Receiver has size-1 slots
        float data[size-1];
        MPI_Request request[size-1];

        // Use tags to sort receives
        for (int tag=0;tag<size-1;++tag){
            printf("Receiver for id %d\n",tag);
            // Non-blocking receive
            MPI_Irecv(data+tag,1,MPI_FLOAT,
                      MPI_ANY_SOURCE,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request[tag]);
        }

        // Wait for all requests to complete
        printf("Waiting...\n");
        MPI_Waitall(size-1,request,MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
        for (size_t i=0;i<size-1;++i){
            printf("%f\n",data[i]);
        }
    } else {
        // Producer
        int id = rank;
        float data = rank;
        printf("Sending {%d}{%f}\n",id,data);
        MPI_Send(&data,1,MPI_FLOAT,size-1,id,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    return MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: This is actually the current implementation I have, with the only difference that I am using Isend for producers, and total amount of data is on the order of GB, which is delivered in ~3000 sends.  It strangely deadlocks if the send ids are really out of order, where some sends can't proceed.  If I sync senders to send in the order of how tags are setup at receiver, the deadlock goes away.  From doc, either way should never deadlock as there are only one matching send/recv for each tag.  That's why I want to pack messages together and try a ANY_SOURCE and ANY_TAG implementation.

Comment: I am sure the deadlock comes from MPI send/recv because the code does not have any other sync mechanism.  Isend/irecv do not consume internal buffer space.  The tags are perfectly matched between sender and receivers.  In fact, the deadlock only manifest if the senders send things heavily out-of-order.  I don't have enough knowledge about openMPI implementation to reason about this behavior, which is against the MPI specification.

Comment: Note that the MPI standard requires acceptable tag values to be from `0` up to `MPI_TAG_UB` with `MPI_TAG_UB` being _at least_ 32767. Some implementations provide higher values for `MPI_TAG_UB` (e.g. 2^31-1) but others don't. If more than 32768 array IDs are used, code that uses tags to identify the arrays will not be portable.